# Hook para crop customizado no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Tenho uma função que **detecta a posição do rosto** da pessoa em uma imagem e retorna o X, Y, W, H ou ela pode retornar a imagem cortada do rosto.

Preciso exibir uma foto de uma pessoa e atualmente estou fazendo:

```
<?= wp_get_attachment_image( 1497, 'custom-small-thumb' ) ?>
```

Certo, ela exibe a foto usando a função clássica de redimensionamento/corte do Wordpress.

MAS o que eu  REALMENTE PRECISO é exibir apenas o rosto que aparece nesta imagem, e eu não queria fazer gambiarra, gostaria de usar o máximo de recursos do Wordpress para esta finalidade.

Eu tenho uma função `faceDetector($imagesrc)` e gostaria de saber se tem algum hook que consigo fazer para executar o ***faceDetector*** antes do ***wp_get_attachment_image***.

Na verdade **eu gostaria** muito de algo como

`<?= wp_get_attachment_image ( 1497, 'face-small-thumb' ) ?>`

Mas o WP não deixa passarmos uma função custom no *add_image_size*.

Answer (score 1):

Vejo duas possibilidades, uma é o filtro `wp_get_attachment_image_src` e a outra `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes`. O primeiro é aplicado logo que as referências da imagem são buscadas no banco de dados (ou seja, em todas as chamadas de imagens), o segundo logo antes de finalizar o markup que será retornado por `wp_get_attachment_image()`.

Em ambos o primeiro parâmetro é um array em que um dos elementos é o `src` (índice 0 ou 'src') que pode ser manipulado e retornado em um novo array.

Exemplo:

```
<?php 
    add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'detectFace' );

    function detectFace( $image ) {
        if ( is_array( $image ) ) { // $image pode ser false em caso de erro
            $novo_src = faceDetector( $image[0] ); // $image[0] é o src
            $image[0] = $novo_src;
        }

        return $image;
    }
```

ref.: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/